# Displaying error message from redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

i've got some error messages (from my API) in my Redux state that I want to display in to my UI

[image: Redux State]

This is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { createUser } from '../../actions';
import './formStyles.scss';
import{ SignUpFormEx }from './SignUpForm/SignUpForm';

interface IProps {
  createUser: any;
  errors: any;
}

const UserCreate: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {
  const error = useSelector<IProps, any>(state => state.errors);

  const useOnSubmit = (formValues: object) => {
    props.createUser(formValues);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Sign Up</h3>
      <SignUpFormEx onSubmit={useOnSubmit}/>
      <p>{error}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  createUser: (userInfo: any) => dispatch(createUser(userInfo))
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(UserCreate);
```

This produces the error:

```
×
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {password, email}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Not really sure where to go from here.
If i try to convert it to an array i get the error: can't convert null or undefined to object.
i've tried `state.errors.username[0]` in useSelector

Probably should note that before data enters the 'error state' the state looks like this:

[image: redux state]

So it'd probably be better to make my state more like this i'm guessing? then i might not get an undefined error? but i'm not sure how to do that or if its right:

```
    "error": {
        "username": [
            null
        ],
        "email": [
            null
        ]
    }
```

Reducer:

```
import { ADD_ERROR, REMOVE_ERROR } from '../actions/types'

export default (state = null, action) => {
  const { type, error } = action;

  switch (type) {
      case REMOVE_ERROR:
          return null;

      case ADD_ERROR:
          return error;
  }
  return state
}
```

Combine reducers:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import authReducer from './authReducer';
import {reducer as formReducer} from 'redux-form';
import userReducer from './userReducer'
import errorReducer from './errorReducer';


export default combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer,
    form: formReducer,
    user: userReducer,
    errors: errorReducer
});
```

Comment: You can try `<p>{error && JSON.stringify(error)}</p>` error is an object and you can't just render an object.

Comment: Obviously that renders to the page but is there a way I can access these in a nicer way? should i change my data structure in my reducer somehow?

Comment: Maybe make an error component: `<SignupErrors errors={error}` and in SignupErros use props.errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to render an object in JSX is not allowed. You need to extract individual properties from the `errors` object and display those individual error strings.

Since `errors` object looks like this:

```
const errors = {
  username: ['invalid username'],
  email: ['invalid email']
}
```

Calling `Object.values(errors)` will return an array that looks like:

```
[["invalid username"], ["invalid email"]]
```

calling `.flat()` function on this returned array will return the flattened array:

```
["invalid username", "invalid email"]
```

So, inside the render function, you could check if `errors` is defined. If it is, turn it into an array using `Object.values()` and `.flat()` function and loop over this array using `.map()` function to show the error messages.

```
{ 
   error && Object.values(error)
                  .flat()
                  .map(err => <p>{ err }</p>)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually tried to do something similar but forgot to check if errors was defined :)